Wrong results of using sizeof operator in C++
I have a question regarding the sizeof() operator.
If you can see my code below in the pic:

When I used sizeof(command), it showed me that the number of bytes was equal to 28:

When I counted by myself, the result must be 26.
Can someone explain to me the reason for that, please?

Please put all code and output directly in the question as text, not a picture of text and not a link to a picture of text.

Do not conflate C and C++. They are different languages with different rules and are moving further apart with each new version of the standards. Questions and answers for the two different languages should be kept separate to help future users of Stack Overflow find the particular information they are looking for. Choose one language, edit the title and the tags to reflect that language, construct a [mre], and edit the question to show that [mre] using only text, not images.

Actually, before proceeding as above, review this question. It likely answers your question, and this question should be deleted.

Just a little FYI: sizeof is not a function (same as, for example, return).

Different machine architectures and compilers have different rules for alignment. Your structure has some padding bytes added in the middle.

See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing

Note that sizeof is an operator, not a function.

This question should be closed as a duplicate, if the (C++) code were presented in the question as code, not an image.  Structure padding and packing would be a valid duplicate, but I prefer Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?  The result hardly needs an image.

Wrong results of using sizeof operator -- The results of sizeof are not wrong.  The results are not what you expected.

When I counted by myself, the result must be 26.  Did you account for the platform and implementation specific alignment padding bytes?

(Gosh, you have to write the code in the body text of your question, instead of a screenshot! AND not the hyperlink either)
To be short, it is not wrong (as the title of the question insists). What you have experienced is called "struct padding", and its fundamental principle is "data structure alignment". It is totally fine and understandable if you didn't know the vocabulary, so that you didn't even know what to search. Now as you know, you can start with the previous Q&A about the same topic here. And the compilers can have different settings for struct padding.
It does nothing with the fixed-size array in it (just in case if you are wondering whether its pointer matters), but it relates to the biggest size of a single variable inside the struct.
In the following generic code that resembles yours,
typedef struct /* unnamed */ {
    uint8_t member1; // 1 byte
    uint8_t member2; // 1 byte
    uint16_t member3; // 2 bytes
    uint16_t member4; // 2 bytes
    int32_t member5; // 4 bytes
    int32_t member6; // 4 bytes
    uint16_t member7; // 2 bytes
    int16_t member8[5]; // 2 * 5 = 10 bytes
} mystruct;
mystruct myinstance = {};

Each sizeof(myinstance.* each member *) is correctly 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, and 10, which sum up to 26, but the sizeof(mystruct) is correctly 28.
According to the struct padding method, it decides the minimum multiplying unit of the structure according to the biggest variable, in this case it is int32_t (4 bytes). So, the entire struct is aligned as a multiple of 4 bytes. This helps CPU's process of locating its variables. You can explore more with this kind of code below:
typedef struct /* unnamed */ {
    uint8_t small; // 1 byte
    uint64_t big; // 8 bytes
} mystruct;
mystruct myinstance;

and calling sizeof(mystruct) will give you 16 because its has the biggest block of uint64_t in it, and any size is adjusted as the multiple of uint64_t's size. Meanwhile, sizeof(myinstance.small) and sizeof(myinstance.big) will give you 1 and 8 respectively. Voilà!
